# SQL Update query with CASE WHEN

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE Table_Main SET filtered = CASE 
WHEN (subTable.name='MI'
 AND subTable.id= Table_Main."CTYPE")  
THEN false  ELSE true END
from subTable
```

the query works only with first row of subTable

Comment: I guess you have to provide where clause to do actual joining

Comment: Thanks the problem is with where :)

Comment: what RDMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table_Main SET filtered = CASE WHEN (subTable.name='CS') 
THEN false ELSE true END 
FROM subTable 
WHERE subTable.id = mainTable."CTYPE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for the MERGE statement (available since SQL Server 2008 I think)!

```
MERGE Table_Main AS Target
USING subTable as Source
ON (Source.name = 'MI' AND Source.id = Target."CTYPE")
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET T.filtered = false
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN UPDATE SET T.filtered = true
OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.*;
```

Comment: UPDATE Table_Main SET filtered = CASE 
WHEN (subTable.name='CS')  
THEN false  ELSE true END
FROM subTable
WHERE subTable.id = mainTable."CTYPE"